# Drag multiple items on a canvas and maintain same distance

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, draggable

I have a Canvas that contains, let's say rectangles to be simple. These rectangles can be single selected, multi selected(two or more rectangles). When I have multi selected rectangles, I want to drag all selected rectangles and maintain the distance between these rectangles.

Any suggestions how to achieve that kind of behaivor?

Best regards,

Gabriel

Comment: Well when moving, add the delta in the mousemove event to all elements current Canvas position, that way you will keep the distance between the objects.

Comment: So I calculate a current point in mousemove, apply the change from the last calculated point and add the difference to all the elements? In that case, 
`code
mousemove(sender, e) { 
lastpoint = currentpoint;
currentpoint = e.GetPosition(this);
changedpoint = lastpoint - currentpoint;
apply changedpoint to all elements;
}
`

Comment: Solved it, if you can make an answer of your statement above, I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well when moving, add the delta in the mousemove event to all elements current Canvas position, that way you will keep the distance between the objects.